# Coordinates of Slider thumb in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

There is some method to know the position of a Slider thumb in `JavaFX`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`getBoundsInParent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getBoundsInParent--) and a [`lookup()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup-java.lang.String-):

```
Bounds bounds = slider.lookup(".thumb").getBoundsInParent();
```

You may need to [`applyCss()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#applyCss--) to the slider before the lookup in order for it to work.

[image: slipslide]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SlipSlide extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Slider slider = new Slider(1, 10, 3);

        slider.setMajorTickUnit(9);
        slider.setMinorTickCount(8);
        slider.setSnapToTicks(true);
        slider.setShowTickMarks(true);
        slider.setShowTickLabels(true);
        slider.setPrefWidth(250);

        Label boundsLabel = new Label();

        VBox layout = new VBox(10, slider, boundsLabel);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));

        stage.show();

        reportThumbBounds(slider, boundsLabel);
        slider.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            reportThumbBounds(slider, boundsLabel);
        });
        slider.boundsInParentProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            reportThumbBounds(slider, boundsLabel);
        });
    }

    private void reportThumbBounds(Slider slider, Label boundsLabel) {
        Bounds bounds = slider.lookup(".thumb").getBoundsInParent();
        boundsLabel.setText(
                String.format(
                        "(%.2f,%.2f) (%.2f,%.2f)",
                        bounds.getMinX(), bounds.getMinY(),
                        bounds.getMaxX(), bounds.getMaxY()
                )
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a little unwanted effect: When I move the thumb quickly sometimes does not mark the position well as if missing update. why?

Comment: JavaFX works based upon a [pulse system](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#A1106308), which usually is capped at 60 frames per second, so updates quicker than 60 frames per second might be coalesced or skipped.  The rate of pulse processing can slow down if the JavaFX application or the system is heavily loaded or if blocking I/O is performed on the JavaFX application thread.  It is not possible, from your description, for me to determine the root cause of your perceived missing update, it is something you will need to track down yourself.